# Probability , Geometric and Gaussian

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

So,I'm good at the questions which require the understanding of basic formulaes , but this one my prof said needs me to think (for the first one)'geometrically'=Stumped. Please Help!
The second is an extra credit and I'm having trouble understanding the problem itself , attempting at solving is far fetched :(

http://postimg.org/image/cpr3vcm4z/

Answer (score 1):

Since the second question is for extra credit, I feel I can explain the *meaning* of any terms you find unfamiliar, and no more. You have not yet specified what it is about the questions that you do not understand.

For the first question, the pair $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$. Draw that square. We are **given** that $X+Y\le 1$. So $(X,Y)$ lies in the square and **below** the line $x+y=1$. Draw that line.

Given that $(X,Y)$ lies below the line, we want to find various probabilities. Let $T$ be the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. This has area $1/2$.

(a) $\Pr(|X-1|\lt 1)$ is very easy, conditional or not. For with probability $1$, this happens.

(b) This one is the hardest. Draw the curve $xy=1$. Find the area $b$ of the part of $T$ that lies below that line, and divide by the area of $T$. To calculate the area $b$, you will need to integrate.

(c) Draw the lines $x=1/2$ and $y=1/2$. Let $c$ be the area of the part of $T$ that lies to the left of $x=1/2$ and below $y=1/2$. Then divide by the area of $T$.

(d) Draw the circle $x^2+y^2=1/4$. Find the area $d$ of the part of the disk that lies inside $T$, and divide by the area of $T$.